# Align TextView inside an image Background of shape Rectangle in different screen sizes

Tags: android, textview, alignment, background-image

I want to align a textview inside a rectangular image in away that it works perfectly in every screen size and in different density screens. 
you can see that in the link provided below that "COMMITMENT" is going out of the rectangular box.
I tried layout_marginTop but it only works on a particular device. alignment changes if the device is changed.
Suggest me some solution:

http://justlikethatapps.com/Screenshot.png

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make that text in that square box then u need to give margin and that margin must come from dimension file  ...and make different dimens file for different screen support..see this image [image]

your main target is mdpi then first make dimens of mdpi ..if margin top is 20 for mdpi then it would be 30 for hdpi and 40 for xhdpi it works